# How can I compare two linked columns from one table with other two linked columns in another table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I need some help on getting the proper formula for validating the following.
We have Customer list with Customer name, Customer number registered in our system, Customer number in another billing system. As we have found some discrepancies in data we need to validate now one old list with the same data with the last updated data in our system.

Meaning we need to compare CU Number+Cu Billing Number column from 1st list with the same two columns from the second list, as we have found out that there are discrepancies and mixtures of CU number and not correct CU billing number next to them:
List 1:

```
CU name     CU number    CU billing number
Aert        BR345        3456
Bert        BR456        2345
Port        BR567        5678
```

List 2:

```
CU name     CU number    CU billing number
Aert        BR345        3456
Bert        BR344        2345
Port        BR567        5678
```

Could you advice what formula can help me cross check the 2 columns from List 1 with the two columns from List 2?

Comment: Welcome to SUper User. Please take a minute to read thru the ***[Help]*** to learn how this site works and how to improve your question with details of what you have researched and attempted to resolve this on your own.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do the two lists contain exactly the same customer names in the same order (guaranteed that if "Port" is the third name on one list, it will be the third name on the other)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please note CharlieRB's comment, there are not enough details in your question so I am basing my answer on some assumptions.  Secondly, this is a very elementary approach to validating your data but it'll do the job relatively quickly.

Assuming your sample table's columns are A, B, and C respectively, and row 1 is used for those headers; add headers "B Column Validation" to E1 and "C Column Validation" to F1 (See image below).

Now using the same layout, paste the back-up data in a separate sheet of the same workbook.

Go back to the original sheet and enter this formula in E2:

```
=IF($B2=Sheet2!$B2, "Good", "Bad")
```

Then this formula in F2:

```
=IF($C2=Sheet2!$C2, "Good", "Bad")
```

*Note: Obviously if your sheet is named differently or your starting cells are in different locations, you'll need to modify your formula to reflect it.*

Drag fill both columns down to the final row of your spreadsheet.  Finally, if you want to color-code it you can use conditional formatting.

[image]

Again, this is a VERY elementary way of doing this and there may be better solutions but this will work if all that you're doing is comparing two columns of data against each other.

Answer (score 1):

This does it

```
Sub EeekPriates()

Dim row As Integer
row = 2

Dim cols(2) As String
cols(0) = "A"
cols(1) = "B"
cols(2) = "C"

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To UBound(cols)

Dim col As String
col = cols(i)

Do While (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(col & row).Value <> "")

    Dim ws1value As String
    Dim ws2value As String

    ws1value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(col & row).Value
    ws2value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(col & row).Value

    If (ws1value <> ws2value) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(col & row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

row = row + 1
Loop
row = 2
Next i

End Sub
```

I copied my data into 2 worksheets

So, Sheet1

[image]

Sheet2

[image]

After the macro runs, sheet2 remains the same as the screenshot above, this is what Sheet1 looks like

[image]